# How to get the titles of the specific tag that I want to query in the postman?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am new and learning DRF, I'm struggling to get the titles of the specific tag that I want to query in the postman, can anyone shed a light on this where I did wrong below? Thank you

models.py

```
 class BookTags(TimeStampedModel):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Tag')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Tags')
        ordering = ['-created']

    book_tags = models.CharField(
        _(u'Tag Name'),
        max_length=255,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.book_tags

class Title(TimeStampedModel):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(
        "BookTags",
        verbose_name=_('tags'),
        blank=True,
    )
```

serializers.py

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    title_set = LibraryTitleSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
## when read_only=True I get an empty list [{}, {}] when (many=True) only gives me an error AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `title_set` on serializer `TagSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Title` instance.


    class Meta:
        model = BookTags
        fields = ['title_set']
```

views.py

```
class TagApiView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.TagSerializer
    search_fields = ['tags__book_tags']
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)

    queryset = Title.objects.all()
```

I want to output titles when I search tags

`localhost:8000/api/tags/?search=Comedy`
when I hit that endpoint it should list all titles that has tag of Comedy

```
[
    {'book_tags': 'Comedy',
     'title': "Title 1",
    },
    {'book_tags': 'Comedy',
     'title': "Title 2",
    }
]
```

urls.py

```
   url(r'^tags/$', views.TagApiView.as_view()),
```

Comment: What is the current output?

Comment: current output is [{}, {}] when I set title_set = LibraryTitleSerializer(read_only=True, many=True) otherwise throws me an error

Comment: I think a property definition on your model may help. But not sure, will wait to see if someone else answers. Your resource scheme is a bit odd. Would expect something like localhost:8000/api/tags/comedy/titles/ or localhost:8000/api/titles/?tags=comedy

Comment: Show your urls. And I can't see in views anything related to your `search` query parameter. I mean it's just a word and DRF won't do anything with it by itself.

Comment: oh yeah I did forgot to include it here, just update my question to include urls

Comment: but you are putting `Title` objects into `TagSerializer` which can serialize only `BookTag` objects, isn't problem here?